# Accessing Redux props with TypeScript in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript

Been struggling to connect the Redux accessed props in a component. This is happening because I was changing a class component to a functional component, so I'm certain is a syntax error on my part:

```
imports...


interface IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp extends StateProps, DispatchProps {
    multipart: IMultipart;
  }

export const InstructorProfilePicture  = ({multipart}: IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp ) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (multipart.videoHolder.instructorId) {
            const instructorQuery: IQuery = { 'styleId.equals': ['2'], 'instructorId.equals': ['' + multipart.videoHolder.instructorId], 'sort': ['publishedAt,desc'], 'publishedAt.specified': ['true'], 'publicationStatus.equals': [MultipartPublicationStatus.Published] };
            getSearchEntities({ query: instructorQuery, outputKey: 'Instructor:' + multipart.videoHolder.instructorId });
        }
    })

    // const { instructorList } = props; this was working on class component

    return (
        <>
        {instructorList && instructorList.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            {instructorList[0].image1 && (<img className="profile-img" src={`${process.env.CDN_S3_DOMAIN}${instructorList[0].image1}`}/>)}
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ multipart, authentication }: IRootState, ownProps) => ({
    instructorList: multipart['Instructor:' + ownProps.multipart.videoHolder.instructorId] as ReadonlyArray<IMultipart>,
    authorization: authentication.authorization
  });
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = { getSearchEntities, setSearchFilters };
  
  type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
  type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(InstructorProfilePicture);
```

In the implementation of the component:

```
<InstructorProfilePicture  multipart={multipart}/>
```

I get this message (these props are coming from Redux):

> Type '{ multipart: IMultipart; }' is missing the following properties
> from type 'IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp': instructorList,
> authorization, getSearchEntities, setSearchFilters

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
interface IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp {
    multipart: IMultipart;
    instructorList: WhatEVER,
    authorization: WhatEVER,
getSearchEntities: the action,
 setSearchFilters: the other action
  }

export const InstructorProfilePicture  = ({multipart}: IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp ) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (multipart.videoHolder.instructorId) {
            const instructorQuery: IQuery = { 'styleId.equals': ['2'], 'instructorId.equals': ['' + multipart.videoHolder.instructorId], 'sort': ['publishedAt,desc'], 'publishedAt.specified': ['true'], 'publicationStatus.equals': [MultipartPublicationStatus.Published] };
            getSearchEntities({ query: instructorQuery, outputKey: 'Instructor:' + multipart.videoHolder.instructorId });
        }
    })

    // const { instructorList } = props; this was working on class component

    return (
        <>
        {instructorList && instructorList.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            {instructorList[0].image1 && (<img className="profile-img" src={`${process.env.CDN_S3_DOMAIN}${instructorList[0].image1}`}/>)}
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ multipart, authentication }: IRootState, ownProps: Partial<IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp>) => ({
    instructorList: multipart['Instructor:' + ownProps.multipart.videoHolder.instructorId],
    authorization: authentication.authorization
  });
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = { getSearchEntities, setSearchFilters };
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(InstructorProfilePicture);
```

You define what should be passed to the base component as `IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp` . here multipart, instructorList, authorization, getSearchEntities, setSearchFilters.

You map the ownProps to be anything of IVideoDetailHeroInstructorProp, so that anything needed for InstructorProfilePicture could be passed as props to it.

This guarantees that InstructorProfilePicture  knows what will be coming as props and the connect will just fill it up with the redux props if needed. This also allows you to use the Picture without redux if needed, e.g. for tests.